# Understanding await purpose within an async function in NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

My question has to do with the `await` purpose in `node.js`. I'm going to write some dummy code in order to express my question, so please don't mind if there's something missing:

```
let f = async function(x) {
    var data = await readFile('x.txt');
    var link = openLink(`./myfile/${data}`);
    return link;
}
```

So, as I understand it, `f` will run in a separate thread from the Nodejs Event Loop while it expects the returning 'promised' value of `link`. When that new thread opens, the function gets executed **synchronously** within that thread - but if that's true, why bother with the `await`? I mean, the function content is executed from top to bottom, like in any synchronous programming language, so it already naturally "waits" for `readFile` to complete in order to continue to the next line and use `data` as a parameter.

I'm surely misunderstanding something here, but as I read articles and documentation about `async` `await` it doesn't get clearer for me why the `await` must be there.

Comment: "*`f` will run in a separate thread*" - no, it won't.

Comment: This [article](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loophttps://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop) might be helpful in understanding "asynchronicity" in JS.

Comment: you need `await` to pause execution of the current function so that the awaited call can resolve the (implicit) promise that's returned by the async function.

Comment: @phuzi by the "current function" you mean the one that has the await call, right? So when I call 'await' it resolves the 'readFile' method in a separate thread while it does something else in parallel while 'f' is paused waiting for 'readFile'? Is that it?

Comment: @elanonrigby No, it pauses the execution of the function marked as `async` (`f` in your case). There is no such thing as an "await call", there is no separate thread or anything. `readFile(…)` is just any promise-returning function, `await` can wait for any promise, regardless how it was constructed.